# Posting binary buffer payload using Node-RED

Tags: http, node-red, protobuf.js

I am trying to send a byte array through POST using Node-RED. I can successfully create the buffer using [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-protocolbuffersnode) and storing it in `msg.payload`. However I can't figure out how to add it as a parameter in a http request node.

The receiving application requires enclosing quotes. So I use the payload in the following url: `localhost:port/path?var=\"{{payload}}\"`, but it gives

> "Error converting http params to args: invalid character '\' looking for beginning of value"

If using it in the request url without quotes: `localhost:port/path?var={{payload}}` nothing gets through (I can see on the other end).

I am using Protobuf due to the application on the other side, but I've also tried creating a buffer, as described here. However, nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSTs should not have arguments in the URL. The data should all be in the body.

Do you need to make the `msg.payload` an object with keys matching the arg names.

```
msg.payload = {
  var = [buffer]
}
```

You will probably have to play around with the content-type header as by default I believe Node-RED will send a JSON body and you probably want `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

You can set the headers by adding a `msg.headers` object

Comment: I have tried to incorporate the var in the payload like you describe and set a header object as well, however, the contents of var are still not included in the http request.

Comment: Apparently the receiving application did its own serialisation, resulting in the seemingly empty response. However, success was dependent on your content-type suggestion and `msg.payload` object declaration, so thank you for that!