# NODE RED http request - post image via API (Face++)

Tags: http, request, nodes, node-red

I have similar problem to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45695651/posting-binary-buffer-payload-using-node-red)

I get an image via a file buffer node. It works fine if this node goes into an visual-recognition node of ibm watson.

I also wanted to use this image to post it into another API. Therefore I use the http request node with URL = https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/detect

And in front of it I use a function node to create **header** and **body** for this http request. It works very good. But I'm not able to "attach" the image to it.

I don't know the correct syntax. It's the line with "image_file".

```
var image = msg.payload;
msg.headers = {};
msg.headers["content-type"] ='application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
msg.payload = {};
msg.payload['api_key'] = 'zrxC';
msg.payload['api_secret'] = 's3UN';
msg.payload['image_file'] = image;
msg.payload['return_landmark'] = '1';
msg.payload['return_attributes'] = 'gender,age,emotion,beauty,skinstatus';
return msg;
```

If I use a different image input (url), it works.

```
msg.payload['image_url'] = 'http://picture.com/pic.jpg";
```

Soooo...syntax ;)

Maybe its also a problem, because the image needs another content-type. Is it possible to give different body parts different content-types?

Edit: I tried something with multipart http requests...here is my whole flow.

```
[{"id":"6c6e1506.29cf2c","type":"tab","label":"Flow 3","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"b84cd67b.aaaee8","type":"http response","z":"6c6e1506.29cf2c","name":"","x":971,"y":602,"wires":[]},{"id":"a220ce16.64fcb","type":"http in","z":"6c6e1506.29cf2c","name":"Get Home Page","url":"/homepage","method":"get","upload":false,"swaggerDoc":"","x":441,"y":590,"wires":[["c46a3f0a.a30cb"]]},{"id":"c46a3f0a.a30cb","type":"template","z":"6c6e1506.29cf2c","name":"Form and Response Template","field":"payload","fieldType":"msg","format":"handlebars","syntax":"mustache","template":" <html>\n     <body>\n        <form action=\"/classify\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">\n            <input type=\"file\" name=\"pic\" accept=\"image/*\"><br>\n            <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">\n        </form> \n        <div>Classifications:</div>\n        <div>\n            {{#result}}\n            <table>\n            <tr>\n                <th>Class</th>\n                <th>Score</th>\n                <th>Type</th>\n            </tr>\n            {{#images}}\n            {{#.}}\n            {{#classifiers}}\n            {{#.}}\n            {{#classes}}\n            {{#.}}\n                <tr>\n                    <td>{{class}}</td>\n                    <td>{{score}}</td> \n                    <td>{{&type_hierarchy}}</td>\n                </tr>                \n            {{/.}} \n            {{/classes}}            \n            {{/.}}            \n            {{/classifiers}}\n            {{/.}}\n            {{/images}}\n            </table>\n            {{/result}}\n        </div>\n     </body>\n</html>","x":720.5,"y":600,"wires":[["b84cd67b.aaaee8"]]},{"id":"ee17076b.7b9038","type":"function","z":"6c6e1506.29cf2c","name":" Determine File Path","func":"if (msg.req.files) {\n    var files = Object.keys(msg.req.files);\n    msg.payload = msg.req.files[files[0]][0].path;    \n}\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":321.5,"y":737,"wires":[["d8385fe9.3b5d4"]]},{"id":"b4bcb13e.bd4a","type":"visual-recognition-v3","z":"6c6e1506.29cf2c","name":"","apikey":"3738dbb4a5ae703eb3d23285127f8a21233e6566","image-feature":"classifyImage","lang":"en","x":701,"y":716,"wires":[["95fdb967.895c98","c46a3f0a.a30cb"]]},{"id":"95fdb967.895c98","type":"debug","z":"6c6e1506.29cf2c","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"complete":"result","x":912.5,"y":760,"wires":[]},{"id":"d8385fe9.3b5d4","type":"file-buffer","z":"6c6e1506.29cf2c","name":"","mode":"asBuffer","x":511,"y":793,"wires":[["b4bcb13e.bd4a","7b398291.92ee0c"]]},{"id":"5c0e525d.d8230c","type":"httpInMultipart","z":"6c6e1506.29cf2c","name":"Classify Image","url":"/classify","method":"post","fields":"[{ \"name\":\"pic\"}]","swaggerDoc":"","x":117,"y":774,"wires":[["ee17076b.7b9038"]]},{"id":"4d5c181f.bdcbe8","type":"http request","z":"6c6e1506.29cf2c","name":"face++","method":"POST","ret":"obj","url":"https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/detect","tls":"","x":797,"y":928,"wires":[["11b9d42c.ae40ec"]]},{"id":"11b9d42c.ae40ec","type":"debug","z":"6c6e1506.29cf2c","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":true,"tostatus":false,"complete":"payload","x":1005,"y":927,"wires":[]},{"id":"7b398291.92ee0c","type":"function","z":"6c6e1506.29cf2c","name":"set payload and headers","func":"var image = msg.payload;\n\n\nmsg.headers = {};\nmsg.headers[\"content-type\"] ='application/x-www-form-urlencoded';\n\nmsg.payload = {};\nmsg.payload['api_key'] = 'z8lK8AM2u7X9CfI5PodNcFYv0OPq3rxC';\nmsg.payload['api_secret'] = 's33uL-coCxnDZn_naWMceZh-Xko1QSUN';\nmsg.payload['image_file'] = [image]; \nmsg.payload['return_landmark'] = '1';\nmsg.payload['return_attributes'] = 'gender,age,emotion,beauty,skinstatus';\n\n\nreturn msg;\n","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":560,"y":933,"wires":[["4d5c181f.bdcbe8"]]}]
```

My problem is to send the image to the red highlighted API.

[image: Flow]

Comment: Nick (@knolleary) pointed out on your earlier question that you'll need to use the node-red-contrib-http-request-multipart for requests like this.

Comment: Yes, but with that node I'm also not able of using the correct syntax to adress the image of the buffer node correctly.

Comment: But you've not shown what you've tried

Comment: I tried something with the explanation that were given [here](https://github.com/sax1johno/node-red-contrib-http-multipart/issues/4)...after that I edited my original post and added my current flow.

Answer (score 0):

To push a buffer as a field you need use the [node-red-contrib-http-request-multipart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-http-request-multipart) to set the `content-type` in the headers to `multipart/form-data`.

Then you need to make sure the `msg.payload` object matches the input needed for the `request` node:

```
var image = msg.payload;
msg.headers = {};
msg.headers["content-type"] ='multipart/form-data';
msg.payload = {};
msg.payload['api_key'] = 'zrxC';
msg.payload['api_secret'] = 's3UN';
msg.payload['image_file'] = image;
msg.payload['return_landmark'] = '1';
msg.payload['return_attributes'] = 'gender,age,emotion,beauty,skinstatus';
return msg;
```

Comment: If I change the content-type to "multipart/form-data' I get:error_message: "MISSING_ARGUMENTS: api_key"

If I'm staying at "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" The api connection works, but the flow is stuck at the upload: 
"MISSING_ARGUMENTS: image_url, image_file, image_base64"